# Why images are blury when extracting image sequence from video clip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image

I have an issue when generating an image sequence from a video clip.
Pictures 1,2,and 3 are three consecutive images from a video clip.
Picture 4 is a close-up of the heel of one of them.
The camera is on a tripod. As you can see there is no issue with the brick wall,
but with any moving part there is.
The camera is a Panasonic HDC-SD100. The clip is AVCHD 1920/1080.
If I use VLC to extract the image sequence there is no issue.
I use all the default settings except for the rendering resolution which I set
to 100% and image compression to 0%.
I have the issue with Blender 2.79b and 2.80.
With this image issue it is impossible to do camera tracking.
Any ideas what I need to do in order to solve this.
Best regards.

[image: enter image description Images from video clip]

Comment: What you are seeing is the result of interlacing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video

Comment: VLC by default will de-interlace the frames and use a blend algorithm. The movie clip editor in blender does not have any options to de-interlace or to interpret the footage as fields. So you will have to transcode the footage first to a format with no fields.

Comment: Does the camera have an option to work with progressive frames? If so, try using that instead. And maybe use a faster speed on the shutter to avoid blurry images. Blurry pics are hard to track accurately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deinterlace your footage. Try this checkbox in the bottom of the Source panel. and if this doesn't work, you'll need to deinterlace your footage outside of Blender first.

[image]

Comment: The sad part is that to do motion tracking there is no way to link the information from the VSE to the movieclip editor. And the movie clip editor lacks a de-interlace function. Importing to the VSE can be used  for exporting a clean version though.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. I have study electronic and television end of the sixties, yes it is not yesterday. In the days of CRT screens interlace video was needed for the eyes. But for digital video it is not really needed anymore. I did not find the deinterlace option in Blender 2.79, but I did in 2.8.
So I did a quick test with 2.8 and it looks great. There you can see what I am up to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1VTozUgvd4. There are two other cartoons.
Many thanks for your help. Take care, Daniel